# Performing a subtraction within a Select statement where one variable has a condition

Tags: sql-server

I have made the query below and now want to modify it to get "Remaining Terms".

It should run on the logic of `MAX(U_RowNo)` which brings the total number of terms minus the terms already paid. The assumption should be that given today's date (date when report with query is run), the remaining terms will be `MAX(U_RowNo)` - (`U_RowNo` where today's date is less than or equal to `U_PaymentDate`)

Query

```
SELECT DISTINCT T0.Code
    , T0.U_CardName
    , T0.U_MRADate
    , T0.U_RentalSchNo
    , T0.U_AssetDesc
    , T0.U_Currency
    , T0.U_AssetCost
    , T0.U_Tenure
    , T0.U_LRPayment
    , T0.U_PaymentTerms
    , T0.U_CommenceDate
    , T1.[Expiry Date]
    , T0.U_BankName AS 'Financier'
    , T2.[Remaining Terms]
FROM [dbo].[@LEASE_HDR] T0
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT U_DocNum
        , MAX(U_PaymentDate) AS 'Expiry Date'
    FROM [dbo].[@LEASE_ROWS]
    GROUP BY U_DocNum
    ) AS T1
    ON T0.Code = T1.U_DocNum
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT U_DocNum
        , (MAX(U_RowNo) - X) AS 'Remaining Terms'
    FROM [dbo].[@LEASE_ROWS]
    GROUP BY U_DocNum
    ) AS T2
    ON T0.Code = T2.U_DocNum
INNER JOIN OCRD T3
    ON T0.U_CardCode = T3.CardCode
WHERE T0.U_Status = 'Contract'
```

Sample Results for [dbo].[@LEASE_ROWS]

[image]

So if a person runs the report on 21st July 2017, the result for `T2.[Remaining Terms]` should be 54 - 6 = 48.
...
22nd July 2017 -> 54 - 6 = 48.
23rd July 2017 -> 54 - 7 = 47.

How do I modify it?

Comment: This part "(U_RowNo where today's date is less than or equal to U_PaymentDate)" might give you more than 1 values. How do you intend to resolve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, this might be what you want.

```
SELECT DISTINCT T0.Code
    , T0.U_CardName
    , T0.U_MRADate
    , T0.U_RentalSchNo
    , T0.U_AssetDesc
    , T0.U_Currency
    , T0.U_AssetCost
    , T0.U_Tenure
    , T0.U_LRPayment
    , T0.U_PaymentTerms
    , T0.U_CommenceDate
    , T1.[Expiry Date]
    , T0.U_BankName AS "Financier"
    , T2.RT1 - COALESCE(T4.RT1,0) AS "Remaining Terms"
FROM [dbo].[@LEASE_HDR] T0
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT U_DocNum
        , MAX(U_PaymentDate) AS 'Expiry Date'
    FROM [dbo].[@LEASE_ROWS]
    GROUP BY U_DocNum
    ) AS T1
    ON T0.Code = T1.U_DocNum
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT U_DocNum
        , MAX(U_RowNo) AS RT1
    FROM [dbo].[@LEASE_ROWS]
    GROUP BY U_DocNum
    ) AS T2
    ON T0.Code = T2.U_DocNum
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT U_DocNum
        , MAX(U_RowNo) AS 'RT2'
    FROM [dbo].[@LEASE_ROWS]
    WHERE U_PaymentDate <= GETDATE()
    GROUP BY U_DocNum
    )   AS T4
    ON T0.Code = T4.U_DocNum
INNER JOIN OCRD T3
    ON T0.U_CardCode = T3.CardCode
WHERE T0.U_Status = 'Contract'
```

Comment: Returns one row. Changed the line "T2.RT1 - COALESCE(T4.RT1,0) AS "Remaining Terms""